# How can I move content of a txt file to another using Bash Script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to copy the whole content of the file into another multiple files as group wise. Suppose If I select 10 .txt files then the contents of those files should be copy and paste in a another one new file. These all files are in the same directory.

I want to do this to multiple files (<2000). So can't do it manually.

Comment: Do you want to combine the contents of multiple files to one file? Do you want to copy the whole content of a file or only part of it? Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve and provide examples.

Comment: What file do you want to copy to? Are all your input files in the same directory? What name should the target files have? Can't you just copy the directory instead? Please [edit] ad clarify what you need.

Comment: Copy the file? Then "the content of the txt file" is copied into another file. You really will need to be more specific on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I want to copy the whole content of the file into another multiple files. What I need to do is a creating a corpus for a research purpose. These files contains with uni codes characters.

Comment: I have edited the question can you please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question needs clarity. There's two possible cases that I can see happening:

1. Copying many to one:

   ```
   for file in directory/*.txt; do cat "$file" >> someotherdir/combined.txt; done
   ```
2. Copying many to many:

   ```
   for file in directory/*.txt; do cp "$file" someotherdir/"$( basename "$file" )".copy ; done
   ```

In each example we're looking at directory named `directory` in your current location ( check that with `pwd` command ). So if I'm in `/home/foo_user` we're looking at `/home/foo_user/directory`. The glob `*.txt` will match all files with `.txt` ending. The destination directory `someotherdir` also will be referenced relative to your current location.  Provide full path such as `/home/foo_user/someotherdir/anotherdir` if you want to copy to specific location. In first example we're using `cat` and `>>` to append contents of all files to single file. In the other `cp` makes a a copy of each file to new filename, which will take out the name of file currently in  `"$file"` variable and append `.copy` to it.

Note that if naming is not of importance, we can reduce second case to just making new directory and copying it recursively via `cp -r`:

```
mkdir copies
cp -r original_dir/ copies/
```

So can be done with first case like `cat dir/*.txt > combined.txt` however loops are preferable when you are dealing with a lot of files and may run into `Argument list too long` error, from which shell loops do not suffer.

Without knowing specific details, these two solutions should suffice for multiple cases. Adapt accordingly to your particular scenario.

Comment: Of the two answers posted, this is the better +1

Answer (score 1):

To copy all the content from file1.txt to file2.txt use the following code:

```
cp file1.txt file2.txt
```

If you know all of the names of the input and output files, you could use a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=(input1.txt input2.txt inputn.txt)
output=(output1.txt output2.txt outputn.txt)
i=0
while (i<="${input#[@]}")
do
    cp "${input[i]}" "${output[i]}"
    i++
done
```

Most of this, however, would depend on the specific situation.

Comment: If you want the array count of elements `${input#}` should be changed `${#input[@]}`. In my tests `${input#}` returns the value of the first element, in your case `input1.txt` which isn't a number at all.

Comment: In addition to that ^, you need `(( ))` for arithmetic, not `( )`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, thank you for the correction